# Encrypted App.exe.Config ConnectionString

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How do I get the ConnectionString from the app.exe.config at runtime when the app.exe.config has been encrypted?

Comment: Presumably *you* encrypted it...so you know *how* it's encrypted....right....?

Comment: I use the ProtectSection to encrypt and UnProtectSection method to decrypt the section. How is the UnProtectSection work if it is running on a client's system and it was originally encrypted on mine?

Answer (score 0):

When you are on the SAME machine and used the standard encryption methods you can access the connection string just like it has never been encrypted.

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[]...
```

You just can't move the config to another machine. Always encrypt on the machine where you want to decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Link with Code Sample...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186234/Encrypt-Net-Configuration-file

Good Luck!